# How to normalize per group in DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to compute percentages per group.

I have data like this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                 


In [2]: data = [{'day': 'D1', 'person': 'John', 'objects': ['apple', 'pear', 'grape']}, 
   ...:         {'day': 'D2', 'person': 'John', 'objects': ['apple']}, 
   ...:         {'day': 'D2', 'person': 'Mary', 'objects': ['kiwi', 'apple']}]                                                                                                                                                                            

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                                                                                                                                                             

  day person               objects
0  D1   John  [apple, pear, grape]
1  D2   John               [apple]
2  D2   Mary         [kiwi, apple]
```

I'd like to compute the percentages of various fruits per people.

I'm starting like this:

```
df.explode('objects').groupby(['person', 'objects']).count()                                                                                                                                        

                day
person objects     
John   apple      2
       grape      1
       pear       1
Mary   apple      1
       kiwi       1
```

Now, how can I normalize per person, to get the following?

```
                day
person objects     
John   apple      0.5
       grape      0.25
       pear       0.25
Mary   apple      0.5
       kiwi       0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just `value_counts` with `normalize` option:

```
(df.explode('objects')
   .groupby(['person']).objects
   .value_counts(normalize=True)
   .to_frame(name='dist')        # replace dist with your desired name
)
```

Output:

```
                dist
person objects      
John   apple    0.50
       grape    0.25
       pear     0.25
Mary   apple    0.50
       kiwi     0.50
```